# Combine targets on a tag in HTML with pure HTML

Tags: javascript, html

HTML5: Is there any way to combine targets on `<a>` tag in HTML with pure HTML? like If you want to open a new window in the parent window or top window?

Something like: `target="_blank && _parent"` **without using JavaSript**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK,** just add my solution which may help somebody...

So what is happening, you basically never need to combine them, as `_blank` only open in `_top` level...

So why it wasn't working for me?

The reason was the **sandbox** on the iframe, so if you need to open a link in `_blank`, make sure you add `allow-popups` in your sandbox list...

Unfortunately, it will fail silently if only using `target="_blank"` in your iframe link, that's why you may not notice that at the first place...